# How to design Login UML diagram?

Tags: django, uml, django-rest-framework

I am using Python2.7 based django-rest-framework. Now I want to design UML diagram for my project.

I want to design UML diagram for following Modules:

1. Login
2. Registration
3. User Profile
4. many more..

anybody can suggest me how can it design ?

Comment: For an examples of how your UML diagrams might look like see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html

Comment: What don't you understand about UML diagrams? What have you created so far? You haven't shown us that you've tried anything yet

Comment: remember there is plenty of different UML diagram types.

Answer (score 0):

Login and Registration are behaviors of your application, while User Profile would be class.
For Login behavior for example you need to define classes which instances will participate in login behavior. Classes for Login (Login Dialog, User etc.) draw in class diagram, Login behavior define as sequence diagram. Add lifelines to represent involved instances in login process and draw messages between them to define interaction. Apply the same procedure in case of registration behavior too. User Profile should be drawn in class diagram. 
I hope it'll help you.